# How to break the 4 words using substring method

Tags: java, substring, spaces

I'm wanting to break up a sentence consisting of 4 words, into individual words. But, I'm not sure how to tell it to start from after the first space and stop and the next space in the sentence.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class arithmetic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)

    String sentence;
    String word1, word2, word3, word4;
    int p, p2;

    System.out.print("Enter a sentence with 4 words:");
    sentence = in.nextLine();

    p = sentence.indexOf(" ");

    word1 = sentence.substring(0,p)+(" ");
    word2 = sentence.substring()(" ");
    word3 = sentence.substring()+(" ");
    word4 = sentence.substring()+(" ");

    sentence = word1+word2+word3+word4;

    System.out.println(sentence);
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)!

```
words = new StringTokenizer(sentence).split("\\s");
```

Now you have an array of strings contained in words, and you can do whatever you want with them, like turn them into another sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `String.split()` method as follows:

```
String[] parts = sentence.split("\\s");
```

which yields exactly the same results as Chris approach.